# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Boolean which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

```
select new
{
    countFair = (pstvte.Fair),
});
```

I have set the default value of the column Fair to "false". Now whem I am assigning this non-nullable boolean value in new field, it gives the below error:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Boolean which is a non-nullable value type

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostVote](
    [PostVoteId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PostId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Fair] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [NotFair] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PostVote] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PostVoteId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostVote] ADD  DEFAULT ('False') FOR [Fair]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PostVote] ADD  DEFAULT ('False') FOR [NotFair]
GO
```

Comment: Are you sure that pstvte is not null?

Comment: It can never be null as I already defined its default value to "False"

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of both countFair and FAIR please?

Comment: It sounds like in the database there might be a null value. Can you confirm whether that is the case?

Comment: Those are the DB definitions. What about the actual code that got generated?

Comment: http://d.pr/i/Dn0j . I have only 2 rows in my table

Comment: are you using linq to sql ?

Comment: @Preet:Update the definition im my question

Comment: just to check if the error in that line, are you tested countFair = (pstvte.Fair) ?? false,

Comment: @Akrem: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change your declaration of `countFair`

From

```
bool countFair;
```

To

```
bool? countFair;
```

**Or**

Do something like this

```
select new
{
    countFair = (pstvte.Fair.HasValue ? pstvte.Fair.Value : false ),
});
```

Comment: or `countFair = pstvte.Fair ?? false,`